# How to find out polygon types inside buffer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I have two polygon layers, one buffer of 20 meters from apartment point data and then urban green area layer with columns like "type of green area" and "attributes of green area".

How can I find out how many of a certain type of green area are within the buffer? I.e. there are 1 forest green area and 2 wetland areas in buffer A etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) buffer with green area
2. Use [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) with buffer Object ID (or some other field unique for each buffer area) and type of green area as `case_fields`

The resulting table will show unique green areas types for each buffer area

Comment: Which statistic type should I choose? If I chose SUM it will sum up the ID which I don't want.

Comment: You can SUM shape area for example

Comment: Ok, I don't think this was the solution I was looking for since this gives me a table which doesn't contain the apartment IDs. I will edit my post for clarity. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: Use apartment ID and type of green area as case_fields

Comment: Ah, that solved the problem. However, this table only shows 1 type, in some buffers there might be more then 1 type inside it.